# Adding an HTML data attribute to rows in Views

Tags: 7, views, theming

I've tried rewriting the row and also theming the Views row, but I'm not having any luck. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I have the format of my view as 'Unformatted View', and in the format settings there is an option to specify the 'Row Class', which is then added to each row. However, I need to add a data-attribute to my rows in addition to a class. The data-attribute needs to be one of the fields - the Taxonomy Term name field (in lower case).

For instance, my field is Taxonomy Term Name. Currently, the HTML markup of each row looks like this:

```
<div class="my-row">Term</a>
```

However, I need it to look like this:

```
<div class="my-row data-attribute=".term">Term</a>
```

I am finding this fairly difficult to accomplish, and can't find much about it online. Could anyone be of help?

Comment: [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978920) on drupal.org shows how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I found to create unique attribute per views row is to override the template file to exclude the outer div and output each row using `Global: Custom text` in the view excluding from display all fields and including them in the `custom text` field.

Here is in more detail

1. go to your view and click `Advanced > theme > information`
2. in `style output` line the bolded file name is the currently used template (let assume `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`)
3. get the name next to the bolded file name (could be something like this `views-view-unformatted--VIEWNAME.tpl.php`)
4. copy `/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` to your `THEMENAME/views-view-unformatted--VIEWNAME.tpl.php`
5. edit it and modify so it does not output the outer row div. It could look like this for unformatted style

   ```
   <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
     <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
       <?php print $row; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```
6. edit all view field and check `Exclude from display`
7. add `Global: Custom text` and add all fields in the content using replacement pattern
8. your outer div in `Custom text` could look like this

   ```
   <div class="views-row my-row" data-attribute=".[field_FIELDNAME]">[field_FIELDNAME]</div>
   ```
9. refresh the cache and make sure in steps 1,2, your new template is used

Answer (score 0):

not seeing that your problem is views module specific.
Maybe here is a solution for your problem outside of views formatting:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1462436#comment-5674366

Comment: I'm referring to a field created in the views module :) not a form field, a views field.

Comment: Ok I see. Then your goal may be accomplished with the [views php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module. Then you can use a php function to attach the data attribute to your field markup. Unfortunately this php programming goes over my head to be of much help in completing this, but the idea may be a starting point. Good luck!

Comment: Just a note: **Views PHP is something everyone should strive to avoid**... but circumstances abound :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the field's tpl.php file .. The needed template and the proper file name can be found at view's setting page >> advanced >> information

Comment: We shouldn't have to override the field.tpl.php file, though.  Maybe if I get some time I can build a module to extend this to the Format Settings where you can set a row class, be able to add `data` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do something similar; I added a `lang` attribute to rows in a search result. Here's what I ended up doing:

Created an override template for the rows in my View of interest. In my case the name was something like "views-view-unformatted--*my-view*.tpl.php"
I copied the existing base "views-view-unformatted.tpl.php" code into that, and made this modification to the  tag printed inside the `foreach ($rows as $id => $row)` loop:

```
<div<?php if(isset($view->result[$id]->entity->language)): ?> lang="<?php echo $view->result->entity->language; ?>"<?php endif; ?>...
```

If you want to use data from a field you're pulling (whether included in the display or not), you can also get the info out of `$view->result[$id]->_entity_properties`. (In my case I didn't need to explicitly capture that field.)